Transmutation of particles "common denominator"
Proton-antiproton annihilation, $$p+\overline p + E_{kinetic} = u\overline d + u\overline u+d\overline u \tag 1$$
reaction and electron-positron anihilation,
$$ e +\overline e + [15-40]\text{GeV} = q\overline q +g  \tag 2 $$
reaction,- they both produce quarks (albeit input particles are different).
Also this nice picture,

shows that by only varying kinetic energies of colliding electron-positron pair one can get almost any particle in the transmutation output.
Hence the question,- if only input energy matters (+ charge surely and couple of other things) for producing any output, maybe that means that deep down "under the hood", all particles are different sides of the same creature ? I.e. does that show that all particles have same roots, i.e. they all are excitation of Higgs field or have some common structure (string theory based or other) ?
Minor question which will clarify post point,- Do we have some theoretical framework which would predict (given input particles and they energies),- possible transmutation outcomes with their respective probabilities ?
Thanks.

Note that you can't get, say, the particles to form a proton, or a graviton, or anything else that violates charge/spin conservations or CPT symmetry. That might play a role. Otherwise, you've functionally just re-thought of string theory.

Sure, all conservation laws must be obeyed. What I'm asking here is best common denominator for such transmutation scheme(s). I'm sure string theory (and their sister theories) is not the only one general explanation, others can exist too.

I'd argue that those conservations laws are the common denominator, is my point. As long as all the physical symmetries are obeyed there's no reason that something can't happen, although our model of physics is incomplete.

Conservation laws and symmetries just draws the boundaries what can and can't happen, but they don't explain why specific reaction has happened at specific conditions. Thus, conservation laws is not a common factor, as (IMHO) better theory should predict reaction schemes given input particles and they energies, especially when by conservation laws multiple reactions for that input energies are allowed.

In that case I've misunderstood the question; I do think it's interesting, though. I would love to know the answer.

Can you make the bizarre Eqn (1) less puzzling??

What do you mean by "less puzzling"? State the outputs as $\pi$ mezons?

You are violating strangeness.

It does not have to be conserved in weak interactions as per wiki description of strangeness. Besides my first given CERN link in the post speaks that such decay is statistically possible.

What's the point of grouping quark-antiquark doublets in the products then? What is your point, and are you seeking vetting thereof?

Point is that such pions are the product of annihilation, sure they are highly unstable and decays fast. My question is written in the post,- I will try to clarify it a bit.

Why is there a K meson in your first equation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon Or is that "K" supposed to mean something else, eg kinetic energy?

It's Kinetic energy term. I'll rename it for removing ambiguity.
